# Looping through an array while grabbing certain elements

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I have a giant dataset that looks like this

[image]

I am trying to go down the list of different companies and grab 3 per company and combine them. Based on the photo above, I would have 2 different lists with 3 companies each (except TH Repair which will have 2 in the final list).

My real dataset contains hundreds of different companies, each with dozens/hundreds of entries so I would finish with dozens of lists (each potentially hundreds long).

I tried to record a macro and ended up with this code

```
Sub Loop1()
'
' Loop1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A4:E6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A18").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A11:E13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A21").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A17:E19").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A24").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

However, this turned out to be WAY more complicated then I expected.

I am looking for the end result to look like this

[image]

Comment: I'll have a solution shortly after I retype all of your sample data.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: where does Mikes Auto Shop number 7 go? It is in your first image but not in list 1 or 2 of the second image

Comment: @PrincessPeach2091 Don't hold your breath, I'm guessing Jeeped was being sarcastic as you took an image rather then providing a CSV or something.

Comment: @don_freem It would go on List 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if something like this works for you.  I only ran one scenario through it so you will want to test it more.

- This makes the assumption that the data is sorted by column B on the original sheet
- This procedure makes an assumption that there is either headers or no data on row 1.
- You will need to change the "Sheet1" in this line `Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to the name of the sheet you are starting with.

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Public Sub MoveData()

      Dim ws1 As Worksheet
      Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

      Dim ws2 As Worksheet
      Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()


      Dim rw As Long
      Dim match_count As Integer
      Dim list_multiplier As Integer
      list_multiplier = 7
      Dim list_row() As Long
      ReDim list_row(0)
      list_row(0) = 2

      For rw = 2 To ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


          If ws1.Range("B" & rw).Value <> ws1.Range("B" & rw).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
              match_count = 0
          Else
              match_count = match_count + 1
          End If

          Dim list_num As Integer
          list_num = match_count \ 3

          If list_num > UBound(list_row, 1) Then
              ReDim Preserve list_row(list_num)
              list_row(list_num) = 2
          End If

          ws2.Cells(list_row(list_num), 1 + list_multiplier * list_num).Value = ws1.Range("A" & rw).Value
          ws2.Cells(list_row(list_num), 2 + list_multiplier * list_num).Value = ws1.Range("B" & rw).Value
          ws2.Cells(list_row(list_num), 3 + list_multiplier * list_num).Value = ws1.Range("C" & rw).Value
          ws2.Cells(list_row(list_num), 4 + list_multiplier * list_num).Value = ws1.Range("D" & rw).Value
          ws2.Cells(list_row(list_num), 5 + list_multiplier * list_num).Value = ws1.Range("E" & rw).Value
          list_row(list_num) = list_row(list_num) + 1

      Next rw

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Actually my real dataset is hundreds of companies long so I would want dozens of different lists (still grabbing 3 from every company though!) I am going to try this code. Thank you

Comment: @PrincessPeach2091 are all the new list on one sheet side by side,  stacked on top of each other, or different sheets?

Comment: Since there would be up to 100 different ones, I'd think the side by side on one sheet is the easiest.

Comment: I edited this code. Try this out now. It should keep adding additional list until it runs out of columns.

Answer (score 0):

When you record your macro, ensure that "Use Relative References" on the Developer Ribbon tab is enabled, :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

assuming row 3 has your data headers, you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim nLists As Long, iList As Long
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim dataToDelete As Range

    With Range("F3", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        data = .Value
        nLists = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Resize(,1))
        nLists = nLists \ 3 + IIf(nLists - 3 * (nLists \ 3) = 0, -1, 0)
    End With

    With Range("A3").Resize(, 6)
        For iList = 0 To nLists
            Set dataToDelete = Nothing
            With .Offset(, iList * 6).Resize(UBound(data))
                .Value = data
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & iList * 3, Criteria2:=">" & (iList + 1) * 3, Operator:=xlOr
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set dataToDelete = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                If Not dataToDelete Is Nothing Then dataToDelete.Delete xlShiftUp
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm I keep getting a "Run time 1004 error. "Unable to get the Max property of the WorksheetFunction class"  http://imgur.com/a/dVf4o

Comment: Your data in the link are different than those in your question where column A has progressive numbering for every different company: you can't ask help showing example data of a kind and then marvel at a provided solution not working with data of a completely different kind! So please edit your question with the final version of data to work with. Thank you

Comment: Apologies! The numbers were just there for reference, but I added them in my real data set and it some what worked. It pulled some weird data out http://imgur.com/a/cOg8P

Comment: why are they weird?

Comment: It grabs randomized versions of companies, not the 3 per company I am trying to get at :/

Comment: I tested with data like that you provided in your question and it worked with no random selection. BTW I edited code to change the statement that defines how many "Lists" are going to be generated where I forced the `\3` operation be evaluated before the  `3*` one. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your task is actually slightly trickier than your online advice suggests. Basically, you have to do the following:

1. Find out how many unique 'keys' (ie unique items in column B) you have. This will tell you the total number of rows you need (ie number of unique keys * 3)
2. Count the number of items for each 'key'. This will tell you how many columns you need (ie max item count / 3 * number of columns in array [A:E = 5])
3. Loop through each line of data and it put on appropriate row for that 'key'. Once three has been reached, jump the column for that key 6 columns to the right, and continue.

If you were to use a `Class` object and `Collection` type of object, this could be really quite concise code, but judging by your post you are at the beginning of your programming journey in VBA. Therefore, I've broken down each task into separate chunks of code so you will hopefully see how arrays can work for you. Once you practise with arrays a little, perhaps you could have a go at making this code more efficient by combining some of the loops:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, dataRows As Long, dataCols As Long, keyLen As Long, maxCount As Long
    Dim keys As String
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim keyArray() As String
    Dim keyCount() As Long, threeCount() As Long, rowNum() As Long, colNum() As Long
    Dim output() As Variant

    'Read the data - change "Sheet1" to your sheet name.
    'Shows how to write range values into a variant to
    'create an array of variants.
    data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value2
    dataRows = UBound(data, 1)
    dataCols = UBound(data, 2)

    'Create a list of unique keys.
    'Note: not the most efficient way, but shows how to
    'create an array from a value-separated string.
    For r = 1 To dataRows
        If InStr(keys, CStr(data(r, 2))) = 0 Then
            If Len(keys) > 0 Then keys = keys & "|"
            keys = keys & CStr(data(r, 2))
        End If
    Next
    keyArray = Split(keys, "|")
    keyLen = UBound(keyArray)

    'Initialise the row and column numbers for each key.
    'Shows how to iterate an array using For Each loop.
    ReDim rowNum(keyLen)
    ReDim colNum(keyLen)
    r = 1
    i = 0
    For Each k In keyArray
        rowNum(i) = r
        colNum(i) = 1
        r = r + 3
        i = i + 1
    Next

    'Count the number of items for each key.
    'Shows how to iterate an array using For [index] loop.
    ReDim keyCount(keyLen)
    For r = 1 To dataRows
        i = IndexOfKey(keyArray, CStr(data(r, 2)))
        keyCount(i) = keyCount(i) + 1
        If keyCount(i) > maxCount Then maxCount = keyCount(i)
    Next

    'Size the output array.
    c = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(maxCount / 3, 1)
    ReDim output(1 To (keyLen + 1) * 3, 1 To c * dataCols + c - 1)

    'Populate the output array.
    ReDim threeCount(keyLen)
    For r = 1 To dataRows
        i = IndexOfKey(keyArray, CStr(data(r, 2)))
        'Copy the columns for this row.
        For c = 1 To dataCols
            output(rowNum(i), colNum(i) + c - 1) = data(r, c)
        Next
        'Increment the count and if it's equals 3 then
        'reset the row num and increase the column number.
        threeCount(i) = threeCount(i) + 1
        rowNum(i) = rowNum(i) + 1
        If threeCount(i) = 3 Then
            rowNum(i) = rowNum(i) - 3
            colNum(i) = colNum(i) + dataCols + 1
            threeCount(i) = 0
        End If
    Next

    'Write the data - change "Sheet2" to your sheet name.
    'Shows how to write an array to a Range.
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3") _
        .Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
End Sub

Private Function IndexOfKey(list() As String, key As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Variant

    'Helper function to find index position of key in array.
    For Each k In list
        If key = k Then
            IndexOfKey = i
            Exit Function
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next

    IndexOfKey = -1
End Function
```